# Passing Char Array into a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, char

I can not access the array from main in the function. How do i correct this ? Whenever I compile it say the argument 1 is of type **char and the argument 1 passed to fre in incompatible. Do i need to change any syntaxes ?

```
void fre(char *asd);

int main()

 {
   char *names[7]={"Jayan Tennakoon","John Long","Robert Lang"};

   int i;

   for(i=0;i<7;i++)
     {

        printf("%s\n",names[i]);

     }

     fre(names);

     return 0;

 }

 void fre(char *asd)
   {
     int i;

     for(i=0;i<7;i++)
       {

          printf("%s\n",asd[i]);

       }
 }
```

Comment: `void fre(char *asd)` --> `void fre(char *asd[])` or `void fre(char **asd)`

Comment: ... and you could pass the number of names too, then `fre` will look rather like `main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Comment: In `main` you have `char *names[7]`, an array of pointers to char.  You attempt to pass this array to function `fre()`.  But `fre` is declared as accepting a single pointer to char.  So it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have a blank line after _every_ line ?

Answer (score 2):

You've declared an array of 7 pointers to char. You initialized it with 3 of them. You need to pass an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array of chars. Based on the comments I'll add a few more ways to declare the arrays that might make it clear what the different ways actually mean.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fre(char *asd[]);

int main(void) {
  char * name  [ ] = {"Jayan Tennakoon","John Long","Robert Lang"};
  char * names [7] = {"Jayan Tennakoon","John Long","Robert Lang"};
  char   names2[7] = {'H', 'e', 'l','l','o','\0'};
  char **names3   = names;

  printf("names2 = %s\n",names2);
  printf("names3[0] = %s\n",names3[0]);
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s\n",names[i]);
  }
  fre(names);
  return 0;

}

void fre(char *asd[]) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s\n",asd[i]);
  }
}
```

I also had to reduce the loop from `7` to `3` or you would experience Undefined Behavior, if lucky this would be a segmentation fault, if unlucky it would likely have printed garbage but exited with a return statue of 0.

Comment: Hi Harry. Thanks it worked perfectly. I have one question, why is it *char[] and not just char[] when i attempt to store the names ?

Comment: What do you mean store the names. Do you mean this `char *names[7]={"Jayan Tennakoon","John Long","Robert Lang"};`

Comment: Have a look at the names2 declaration and compare it with how names is declared etc.

Comment: Look at names2 that I added to the original answer. Note the difference between it and names. `names` is a pointer to a pointer, in this case we're allocating space for it by using `[7]`.

Comment: why can't I just use char[]={"Arvind Asd"," John Lang", "Mike asdert"} ?

Comment: `name[]` would be to an array of chars, not an array of char pointers. You could use this `char *name[] = {...}`. I added another declaration to the answer that might help.

Comment: Can you accept my answer if it answered your question?

Comment: yeah i can. it works perfectly. sorry i just saw this msg.

Comment: Hey can i ask u another question.

Comment: If it's related to this one sure. If it's completely unrelated it might be better as another question on SO.

Comment: yes it is a totally different problem, can i tag u in that question ?

Comment: and how do i tag ?

Comment: If it does not have a good answer then bung the link in here and if I can help I will.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171421/i-can-not-input-the-names-into-the-char-array-using-scanf

Comment: this is the link. hope you could help me

Answer (score 0):

With

```
char *names[7]={"Jayan Tennakoon","John Long","Robert Lang"};
```

You have an array of pointers to `char`. So

```
void fre(char *asd)
```

should be

```
void fre( char *asd[], int n) 
/* it is good to pass the total(here 3) 
 * since you have initialized the first three elements
 */
{
.
.
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
.
.
```