# I can not input the names into the char array using scanf

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, char, scanf

I can not use scanf to enter a name in stdnames array.
     when compiled it had no error , but as soon as i enter a name and 
    then press enter to write the other name it gives an error and shuts the program.
    How should I go about it ?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  float marks[50];
  /*char *stdnames[100]={"Arvind Thillainathan","Robert Lang"};*/
 //I want to stores names like the above one
  char *stdnames[100];
  int totalNames = 0;
  int i = 0, w=0,h=0;

 printf("How many names do you want to enter ??\n");
 scanf("%d",&totalNames);
 assert(totalNames != 0);

 for(int count = 0; count < totalNames; count++)
 {
     printf("Enter name of student\n");
     scanf("%s",stdnames[count]);
 //From here the problem starts
 }
 getres(marks,totalNames);

 for(i = 0; i < totalNames; i++) 
      {
        int v = 1;
        printf("\n");
        printf("IELTS Marks of %s\n\n",stdnames[i]);
        for(h = w; h < w+5; h++)
           {
            if(v==1)
            {
                printf("Listening : %0.1f\n", marks[h]);
            }
            else if(v==2)
            {
                printf("Reading   : %0.1f\n", marks[h]);    
            }
            else if(v==3)
            {
                printf("Writing   : %0.1f\n", marks[h]);    
            }
            else if(v==4)
            {
                printf("Speaking  : %0.1f\n", marks[h]);    
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Overall   : %0.1f\n\n", marks[h]);
            }
            v++;
            //if(h==10)
            //{
            //  break;
            //}
        }
        w+=5;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're scanfing to an unallocated object `stdnames[count]`. Perhaps try allocating some memory there first with say `malloc`.

Comment: You might also run into trouble with `float marks[50];` when you have `char *stdnames[100];` although the loop that inputs marks is a bit obfuscated.

Comment: There is no "char array". You mean that array of pointers to `char`?

Comment: @arvind-dexter-thillainathan : consider including the definition for `getres(marks,totalNames)` in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By

```
char *stdnames[100];
```

you got an array of (pointers to char).

The NEXT BIG QUESTION  is

Who will allocate memory for each of these pointers?

A small answer would be - You have to do it yourself like below :

```
stdnames[count]=malloc(100*sizeof(char)); // You may replace 100 with desired size
```

or

```
stdnames[count]=malloc(100); // sizeof(char) is almost always 1
```

You need to put this line before the `scanf` statement.

**Note:** Don't forget to free the allocated memory once these variables become irrelevant. Do it like :

```
free(stdnames[count]);
```

Comment: That boldfaces hurts in the eyes. And `sizeof(char)` is useless, as it will never yield something other than `1`.

Comment: @Olaf : Hurted mine too. changed :D

Comment: Thanks (still it is a bit too loud for me, but I can stand that - have to read Word-Docs and PPT anyway). There are other issues with the contents.

Comment: Ehm, that would be correct (and independent of the type), but actually I wonder why not just remove that term?

Comment: @sjsam thanks man, it worked perfectly. I just started C. What's the exact purpose of malloc ?

Comment: also when i type "Robert Lang" with a space it skips one turn. I know scanf cant accept space, but how do you counter it ?

Comment: @ArvindDexterThillainathan : . `malloc` is used for allocating memory. If you're a beginner, consider reading Stephen Prata's C Primer Plus. It is a great book to start C with. Latest edition is 6

Comment: @ArvindDexterThillainathan : scanf normally reads the input upto the first white space, that is why it accepts "Robert" rejects "Lang" :D. Use `fgets` instead..

Comment: Done. Thanks man. But when you declare an array won't it allocate memory ? why use malloc ?   sure, i will read that book.

Comment: You declared an array of pointers actually. Had it been `char stdnames[100]`, the story would have been different.  Follow the book I have suggested, you will understand the difference between `char stdnames[100]` & `char* stdnames[100]` Also when posting questions, do your homework thoroughly. Otherwise you may get an influx of downvotes which can become embarrassing. If the questions are clear and they prove your effort Stack Overflow  will be a great place to learn :D

Comment: sure, thanks man. one more help please. if i use i use fgets instead of scanf, what changes should i make ?

Comment: Instead of `scanf("%s",stdnames[count]);` use `fgets(stdnames[count],100,stdin)`. Here 100 is the I have used in `malloc`. For more information see [fgets manual](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)

Comment: You are good man. It works. but when i use fputs(stdnames[i],stdout) it does not print the whole name. it prints the name after the whitespace. why is that ? thank you.

Comment: @ArvindDexterThillainathan : That seems weird !

Comment: @sjsam that book you recommended is amazing. can u recommend me a book for python ?

Comment: @ArvindDexterThillainathan : I have never done python programming in my life, so not in a position to recommend one :(

Comment: @sjsam oh okay. any other programming language book you could recommend ? like C++ or ruby ?

Comment: @ArvindDexterThillainathan : For C++ Stephen Prata has written one called C++ Primer Plus. Though I have never read it, I guess it should be good. & I have never done any ruby stuff :( sorry